# Some C++ code is giving error in one project and compiles fine in another project?

Tags: c++, xcode

The following code compiles fine in one C++ project in `RenderingEngine.cpp`:

```
IRenderingEngine* CreateRenderer1()
{
    return new RenderingEngine1();
}
```

but if I start a new project in Xcode 4.3.2, it gives error:

> Allocating an object of abstract class type 'RenderingEngine1'

The definition is in `IRenderingEngine.hpp`

```
struct IRenderingEngine {
    virtual void Initialize(int width, int height) = 0;    
    virtual void Render() const = 0;
    virtual void UpdateAnimation(float timeStep) = 0;
    virtual void OnRotate(DeviceOrientation newOrientation) = 0;
    virtual ~IRenderingEngine() {}
};
```

How can this be fixed?  (this is part of [iPhone 3D Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596804831.do) in its [project 1](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596804831/HelloArrow/)).

**Update: in `RenderingEngine.cpp`:**

```
public:
    RenderingEngine1();
    void Initialize(int width, int height);
    void Render() const;
    void UpdateAnimation(float timeStep);
    void onRotate(DeviceOrientation newOrientation);

private:
    GLuint m_framebuffer;
    GLuint m_renderbuffer;

};
```

and those 5 functions are all defined.  (the last two are dummy -- all empty for now)

Comment: Can you please provide the definition for class `RenderingEngine1`?

Comment: please see update in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say it depends how you're using the returned `IRenderingEngine` pointer. As the project compiles in one project, you must have implemented all the necessary pure virtual functions from the base class. In the failing compilation, you must be missing an implementation or two.

Why it compiles in the 'book' example, but not your example is difficult to say with the information you've given. I would check through the build output to ensure that the source files you are compiling (header and implementation for both classes) are exactly the ones you think that they are. It's possible you are picking up another version of `IRenderingEngine` which does not have all the required pure virtual implementations.

Comment: yeah, i wonder why the computer doesn't say "onRotate is not implemented and therefore RenderingEngine1 remains a virtual class..." So we have to hunt down what isn't implemented one by one

Comment: @JeremyL `onRotate` is not the same as `OnRotate`.

Comment: @JeremyL: Note sure about the environment that you're using. In GCC, you'd normally get something like `error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type Derived because the following virtual functions are pure within Base: virtual void Base::bar()` Have you checked the full output of your build? Can you turn up the verbosity of the compiler? Increase the warning level? Use a different compiler as a cross reference?

Comment: I just tried GNU99 and it is the same error message... oh well... yeah I think it might be smart to at least give a warning that the class is not fully implemented... there is no warning at all.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by providing implementations for **ALL** pure virtual base methods.

I'm assuming `RenderingEngine1` inherits from `IRenderingEngine`. So override and implement

```
virtual void Initialize(int width, int height) = 0;    
virtual void Render() const = 0;
virtual void UpdateAnimation(float timeStep) = 0;
virtual void OnRotate(DeviceOrientation newOrientation) = 0;
```

Comment: how come it compiles in the book sample but not here... what has to be done?

Comment: @JeremyL does the book come with a compiler?

Comment: it uses C99 as specified in the project file

Comment: @JeremyL does `RenderingEngine1` provide an implementation for those functions?

Comment: I think it does as it says in the `public:` that `void UpdateAnimation(float timeStep) {}` and `void onRotate(DeviceOrientation newOrientation) {}` and have longer definition of `Render` and `Initialize` down below...

Comment: @JeremyL in that case it can't compile anywhere, since Render and Initialize remain abstract. If it does (which I doubt) your compiler is wrong. Implement those methods in the deriving class and it will work.

Comment: So I put in empty functions... just like `Initialize` except the function does nothing...  I removed those `{}` from the `public:`... and it is still not compiling

Comment: @JeremyL those `{}` **ARE** the implementation. Just declaring the functions is not enough, you have to implement the - i.e. add `{}`.

Comment: @JeremyL please don't ignore comments. I know what I'm saying, but if you don't want help, don't ask questions. I already said just declaring the functions (which you do in your update) is not enough, and that you should implement them. I believe I have given you sufficient information to solve this problem and will not waste any more time. Sorry!

Comment: @JeremyL also, not that `onRotate` is not the same as `OnRotate`.

Comment: yeah, it is due to `onRotate` vs `OnRotate`.  Not that I don't read comment.  The compiler won't say `OnRotate` not implemented but just say can't instantiated... this kind of tricky things doesn't happen in Objective-C side of Xcode -- or maybe I haven't seen it yet

Comment: you want to add that to your answer so I will accept your answer?

Comment: @JeremyL my answer already states (and it has for 40 minutes) that you should provide an implementation for `OnRotate`, so I don't think it needs editing.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while reading through that first chapter. It was very frustrating.

I just discovered that you can click on the **red** error message (on the right side) where it says,

> Allocating an object of abstract class type...

Xcode will directly switch to that IRenderingEngine.hpp file and say what the problem is in **gray** color.